# ng-repeat animation complete callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

So I have a simple ng-repeat with enter animation defined in javascript.

Sandbox: http://codepen.io/anri82/pen/KwgGeY

Code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  {{state}}
  <ul>
     <li class="repeat-animate" ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
  <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller("MyController", function($scope) { 
   $scope.state ="idle";
   $scope.id=3;
   $scope.list = [1,2];
   $scope.add = function () {
     $scope.state="pushing";
     $scope.list.push($scope.id++);
     $scope.state="done pushing";
   }; 
}).animation('.repeat-animate', function () {
  return {
    enter: function (element, done) {
      element.hide().show(2000, done);
    }
  };
});
```

How do I switch `$scope.state` to `done pushing` only *after* animation is complete? Answer should be in angular way, don't suggest `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the javascript animation approach you are doing, you would need to get hold of the scope of the current element within the animation's done callback. Since it is outside of angular context after updating the variable you need to manually invoke the digest cycle by doing `$scope.$apply()` (or use `$timeout`, `scope.$evalAsync` and so on). And also since ng-repeat creates a child scope, element's scope would actually have the inherited property `state` from the parent controller scope, so in-order for the update to get reflected on the parent scope, use an object to wrap `state` property, so that both child scope and parent has the same object reference.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
.controller("MyController", function($scope) { 
  $scope.push = {state: "idle" }; 
  $scope.id=3;
  $scope.list = [1,2];
  $scope.add = function () {
    $scope.push.state="pushing";
    $scope.list.push($scope.id++);

  }; 
}).animation('.repeat-animate', function () {
  return {
    enter: function (element, done) {
     element.hide().show(2000, function(){
          var scope = element.scope(); //Get the scope
          scope.$evalAsync(function(){ //Push it to async queue
             scope.push.state="done pushing"
          }); 
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPROLe)**

Comment: $evalAsync should take a string, no? Right now your code performs the assignment and passes `"done pushing"` to `scope.$evalAsync`, which is no different than doing `scope.push.state="done pushing"; scope.$evalAsync();`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Ofcourse no difference it is just written in one line, [it can take any expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync). and here it just does not matter

Comment: Oh I see, it would make the intent more clear if split in two lines. What I mean is, `$evalAsync` optionally takes an expression, and your code has a side-effect of passing `"done pushing"` as an (invalid) angular expression to be evaluated which throws an error in the console.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I agree, i have updated as it is more readable, and there is no _invalid_ angular expression, but it will just try to evaluate the property on the scope which does not exist.

Comment: is there a difference between `angular.element(this).scope()` and `element.scope()`?

Comment: @Anri Not really, infact no need to do angular.element because element is already being wrapped and so i updated.

Comment: @PSL +1 for making it readable, but there **are** invalid angular expressions -- that is when it fails to `$parse`. Your old code `scope.$evalAsync(scope.state = "done pushing");` first performs the assignment and returns the assigned value (`"done pushing"`) to be evaluated by `$evalAsync` which throws an `Error: [$parse:syntax]`. [See for yourself](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoRmeE) (click "Add" and open DevTools console to view errors).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté oh yeah it becomes invalid expression since there is a space in the string, which is evaluated as property...

Comment: Of course, that error doesn't matter much now that you've already updated the code. `;)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté @PSL new challange, kind sirs. If you will look at this updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anri82/pen/YPGJMY You will see that this solution does not work for `leave` animation, because at the time we want to adress scope - it is already destroyed. Any ideas? Should i make another question?

Comment: Ok, i solved it like this `element.parent().scope()`