# Focus a dynamically created input using ng-repeat - AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to create a bunch of inputs. The `ng-repeat` loops through an array to know how many inputs to produce. The problem comes when I click a button and it pushes a new input into the `ng-repeat` array, this updates the view and a new input is visible. However, I want to gain focus of this new input. How can I do this? Here is my current code,

**JS Controller**

```
app.controller('setCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.inputs = [];
  var inputCounter = 7;
  for(var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) $scope.inputs.push( {counter: i, first: '', second: ''} );

  // Function to add new input and then gain focus of new input
  $scope.addInput = function() {
    $scope.inputs.push( {counter: ++inputCounter, first: '', second: ''} );
    var focus = "#input" + inputCounter;
    $(focus).focus();
  }

}]);
```

**HTML / ng-repeat**

```
<div ng-repeat="input in inputs" class="col-xs-12" style="padding-top:12px;">
  <div class="col-xs-6 input-wrapper-left">
    <div class="input-counter">
      {{input.counter}}
    </div>
    <div id="input{{input.counter}}" class="input-input input-left" contenteditable>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the above code creates the new input but it will not focus it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions for it, You can use the the first one or the  second approach however it will require to add animation to your ng-repeat. [please check this ng-repeat animation complete callback to understand how you can use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681546/ng-repeat-animation-complete-callback). Basically in callback call `element.focus()`

**Method1:**

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meJRqV?editors=101

```
$scope.addInput = function()
{
    $scope.inputs.push( {counter: ++inputCounter, first: '', second: ''} );

    $timeout(function()
    {
        // have to do this in a $timemout because
        // we want it to happen after the view is updated
       // with the newly added input
       angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('input'))
       .eq(-1)[0]
       .focus();
    }, 0);
}
```

**Method 2:**

Codepen: http://codepen.io/ev-tt/pen/BNXBmd?editors=101

```
.animation('.repeat-animate', function () {
  return {
    enter: function (element, done) {
      element.hide().show(100, function(){
        var scope = element.scope();
        scope.$evalAsync(function(){ 
          element.find(':last')[0].focus();
        }); 
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This Question is already answered please check out the links below:

1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162684/4578345

2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445706/4578345